# How to disable SpagoBI POST to GET call conversion

Tags: java, tomcat7, http-request, spagobi

I am using SPAGOBI 5.1 as reporting tool.
The software in GRAY-BOX-Testing came up with issue that,
it allows response to POST call query when it is converted to GET call.
so how to come out with such issues.
Where actual call type is POST & testing team has manually send the IP Packats by converting POST to GET & still receives the same response from Spago Server.

I am using Tomcat 7.0.47 for the same & JDK 1.7